# Does the Laurent series of $e^{1/z}$ centred at $z=1$ have any non-zero terms of negative exponent? What is the radius of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, laurent-series

I have been struggling with this problem for a while. So far, this is what I have managed to obtain. I have little faith in my solution. If my answer is wrong, could someone give me a hint?

We know that the Laurent series of $e^{1/z}$ centred at $z=1$ will be of the form

$$e^{1/z}=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n = \left(...+\frac{a_{-2}}{(z-1)^2} +\frac{a_{-1}}{(z-1)^1} + a_{0} + a_1(z-1)+a_2(z-1)^2 + ... \right)$$

At $z=1$, we see that the function $e^{1/z}$ is defined and has no singularity. Thus $a_n = 0$ if $n < 0$. So it does not have any non-zero terms of negative exponent.

As for the radius of convergence, we note that the $z=0$ gives us an essential singularity, so the radius of convergence is $R = 1$.

Comment: The title says the series is centered at $0$

Comment: @jjagmath My apologies, I fixed it.

Comment: As I commented on [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575130/laurent-series-of-e1-z-centred-at-z-1), there are two possible Laurent series, so you should explicitly specify which one you're interested in. From the last sentence, it seems you are interested in the Laurent series on the disk $\{|z-1|<1\}$. In that case, yes, the function is analytic on that disk and thus its Laurent series is actually a regular power series.

Comment: @GregMartin I am interested in the case where $|z-1|<1$. I am specifically interested in whether my reasoning for no non-zero terms of negative exponent is correct.

Comment: For your last sentence, you need to also note that there are no other singularities within a radius of $1$. But other than that, your reasoning is correct.